# how to give url of local image file

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get URI from an asset File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820816/how-to-get-uri-from-an-asset-file)

i have a image in my assets folder   bill.png  how do i give url of that file? how to access that file by url?

what do i do? give url of file indtead of http url

```
 GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint((int)(51.515259*1E6),(int)(-0.086623*1E6));
    CustomOverlayItem overlayItem2 = new CustomOverlayItem(point2, "GoldenEye  
 (1995)", 
            "(Interiors Russian defence ministry council chambers in  
 St Petersburg)", 
            "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images 

  BMzk2OTg4MTk1NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjExNTgzNA@@._V1._SX40_CR0,0,40,54_.jpg");       
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem2);

    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
```

Comment: yes im here how i read image fromlocal assets folder

Comment: no one answer me plzhelp me

Comment: Look at the duplicate link. We helped.

Answer (score 0):

see this link. there is a assets properties. `getBitmapFromAsset().` you can get image and set in imageview.

[In Android, can I use image from assets in layout xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776445/in-android-can-i-use-image-from-assets-in-layout-xml)

Comment: no i wanna read local image by url according to my application

Comment: @hayyaanam mean you tag that i want to read image form assets folder how ? now what you want ? do you want relative path of assets ?